# Vert.X Inspect JWT token for expiration time

Tags: jwt, vert.x

I have the following scenario, in my vertx application I have an endpoint /login that after receiving correct credentials is issuing a JWT with 30 minutes validity.

I use this token to protect all routes under /api/* endpoints.

All of this is working as expected.

My problem is that I want to be able to intercept those /api/* requests and just before doing the token authentication to inspect the token and if it is about to expire to generate a new one that can be returned in the headers of the response so the client can use it on consequent requests.

What I want to achieve is:

1. avoid issuing forever valid tokens as if leaked I have no way to prevent access to the application
2. avoid maintaining a token blacklist of anykind
3. avoid having to issue very short living tokens and reissue those on every request

In general any kind of strategy is welcome.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to add the same route multiple times? See http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-web/java/#_route_order

Comment: Hi @alexvetter, I dont have problems intercepting the route, my issue is with the mechanics of inspecting the token, either me or vertx lack this ability. One thing that I have probably miss to note is that I am using javascript.

Comment: Mhm, the JWT is included in the Header and the [`JWTAuthHandlerImpl`](https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-web/blob/master/vertx-web/src/main/java/io/vertx/ext/web/handler/impl/JWTAuthHandlerImpl.java) parses the headers. Perhaps you need to implement something similar to the `JWTAuthHandlerImpl`.

Comment: Let me know what your solution is. I need to implement authentication soon and it's feels like I will have a similar problem.

Comment: It would be nice if you can share the source code; I'm also interested in this approach...

Comment: For now the only solution I could think of is to forget about #3 and just issue a new token on every request and return it in the response headers. The tokens are signed for 30 minutes, which creates a something like a 30 minutes `session` of inactivity for the end user, keep in mind that this is still completely stateless and very scalable.

this is how i sign the token:
```javascript
            token = this.authProvider.generateToken({ "sub": params.post.username }, {
                expiresInMinutes:         this.getApp().getConfig("auth.token.expiresInMinutes")
            });
```

Answer (score 3):

In order to handle a request before the JWT validation all you need to do is add your custom handler before the Auth handler e.g.:

Router router = Router.router(vertx);

```
// Create a JWT Auth Provider
JWTAuth jwt = JWTAuth.create(vertx, new JsonObject()
    .put("keyStore", new JsonObject()
        .put("type", "jceks")
        .put("path", "keystore.jceks")
        .put("password", "secret")));

router.route("/api/*").handler(ctx -> {
  // here do what you're planning to achieve, and the call
  ctx.next();
});

// protect the API
router.route("/api/*").handler(JWTAuthHandler.create(jwt, "/api/newToken"));
```